# I18n Syntax Ruby on Rail error f.input_field

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, syntax-error, rails-i18n

I am trying to add I18n translations to replace `HelloWorld` with some translations in my `RoR` application:

```
<%= f.input_field :misc_details, as: :text, rows: 2, placeholder: HelloWorld %>
```

I added the below key to current `en.yml` file:

```
en:
  onboarding:
    q22: HelloWorld
```

and modified my `.html.erb` file as follows:

```
<%= f.input_field :misc_details, as: :text, rows: 2, placeholder: t('onboarding.q22') %>
```

but it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you restart the server?

Comment: can you share full directory of this view file